# My texture file is not being found for my block, I had the same problem but with a json file for an item, I asked about that on here and it was fixed

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge, file-not-found, filenotfounderror

Pretty much I'm making a minecraft mod on intellij (Eclipse doesnt work for me) and it couldnt find any json files or textures for an item I was making, someone told me to add a line of code to the gradle and it fixed. But now it cant find the texture of the block im now adding. Here is the tutorial I followed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=42z8_UDLmk4

[image]

If anyone knows why, please tell me.

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me which version are you working upon?

Answer (score 0):

The package "*assets.myfirstmod*" isn't necessary such as you are already in a ressource folder.

The texture should be on:

```
src/resources/textures/blocks/block_copper.png
```

Comment: The package assets.myfirstmod is absolutely necessary.